# Filling missing values with values from most similar row

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have the following table. Some values are NaNs. Let's assume that columns are highly correlated. Taking `row 0` and `row 5` I say that value in `col2` will be `4.0`. Same situation for `row 1` and `row 4`. But in case of `row 6`, there is no perfectly matching sample so I should take most similar row - in this case, `row 0` and change NaN to `3.0`.
How should I approach it? Is there any pandas function that can do this?

```
example = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [3, 2, 8, 4, 2, 3, np.nan], 
                        "col2": [4, 3, 6, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 5], 
                        "col3": [7, 8, 9, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 7], 
                        "col4": [7, 8, 9, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 6]})
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   3.0     4.0     7.0     7.0
1   2.0     3.0     8.0     8.0
2   8.0     6.0     9.0     9.0
3   4.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   2.0     3.0     NaN     NaN
5   3.0     NaN     7.0     7.0
6   NaN     5.0     7.0     6.0
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive to what you mean by similar? Is it just the minimum difference between the sum of the rows?

Comment: The challenge with this is to define what it means to be the 'most similar' row.  One way would be the row with the minimum sum of the squared differences between all non-NaN values.

Comment: Data Science is highly domain specific. The kind of data, the type of application and the problem statement will determine what sort of action you must take. In many cases, you might want to altogether remove ```NaN``` values. Or sometimes, you would want to replace them with the median or the mean of the feature. And if you're using high level algorithms they might take care of missing values themselves.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Exactly, the euclidean distance I think

Comment: Just a note not directly related to your question. If that table describes some sort of _population_ of interest, your filling method could be highly questionable (and computationally expensive).

Comment: @jukebox, I'm planning to remove those rows during training, but the problem is that validation data also contains NaNs - I'm not sure how should I treat it

Comment: @MarkAlanFrank https://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-missing-data-python/  This article might help. It has a few examples as well. Maybe studying this might give you a way to deal with ```NaN``` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a hard question , involved `numpy` broadcast  , and `groupby` +  `transform` , I am using `first` here , since `first` will pick up the first not `NaN` value

```
s=df.values
t=np.all((s==s[:,None])|np.isnan(s),-1)
idx=pd.DataFrame(t).where(t).stack().index
# we get the pair for each row
df=df.reindex(idx.get_level_values(1))
# reorder our df to the idx we just get 
df.groupby(level=[0]).transform('first').groupby(level=1).first()
# using two times groupby with first , get what we need .
Out[217]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   3.0   4.0   7.0   7.0
1   2.0   3.0   8.0   8.0
2   8.0   6.0   9.0   9.0
3   4.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
4   2.0   3.0   8.0   8.0
5   3.0   4.0   7.0   7.0
6   NaN   5.0   7.0   6.0
```